# can expand.grid create "numeric" instead of "list"?

Tags: r

I was expecting this to produce an object of mode `numeric`

```
R> mode(expand.grid(c(1,2),c(3,4)))
R> "list"
```

Is there an easy fix for making it "numeric"?

Comment: the result of `expand.grid` is a data frame, so just use `as.matrix`

Comment: It is a list of numeric values str(expand.grid(c(1,2),c(3,4)))

Comment: Rather than `as.matrix` the usual coercion function is `data.matrix`. The difference is that the result will be assured of being numeric in cases where there is a mixture of numeric and factor columns. Admittedly, in this case, it wouldn't matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making numericals, the code below shows what you are making - and how to make it a matrix instead of lists:

```
> x <- as.matrix(expand.grid(c(1,2), c(3,4)))
> x
     Var1 Var2
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    2    3
[3,]    1    4
[4,]    2    4
```

As you can see the components are numerical lists/vectors:

```
> str(x)
 num [1:4, 1:2] 1 2 1 2 3 3 4 4
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:2] "Var1" "Var2"
> x[,1]
[1] 1 2 1 2
```